# How long hibernate locks table during select?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Suppose a [Criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) is created and then method `Criteria.list()` is called. It returns `N` results from table `MyTalbe` (there is not joins for simplicity). So how long hibernate lock records in `MyTable`? Does it lock all selected rows until all iterated? Or it lock rows untill session is opened (if yes when it s closed if I do not invoke close on session)?

**Note**

Database is MySql.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not lock the tables after a select. If you need to block for a particular reason you need to do explicitly.

Comment: So table is locked duting select?

Comment: The tables are not locked completelly if you don't do this explicitly